# Is there a way to connect to an encrypted TCP server using Winsock?

Tags: c, ssl, winapi, winsock2

Winsock [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-secure-socket-extensions) mentions IPsec secure extension for sockets but it does not mention SSL anywhere, Is there a way to use SSL with the created socket without using third party libraries such as OpenSSL or WolfSSL?

The closest thing I found was official MS examples on [github](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/netds/winsock/securesocket/stcpclient/tcpclient.c) but there is no mention of SSL and public and private keys.

Can anyone provide an insight on how to achieve such goal, what functions to use?

Comment: In the example you have linked you can see it is just `WSASetSocketSecurity`, `WSASetSocketPeerTargetName` calls before `WSAConnect`. You can just use the initialized socket to setup regular TLS e.g. with builtin [Schannel API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/secure-channel).

Comment: There are several links to Schannel examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032056/compilable-c-code-to-implement-a-secure-sll-tls-client-using-ms-sspi) discussion: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116110926/http://www.coastrd.com/c-schannel-smtp) you can see they do `ConnectToServer` and then `PerformClientHandshake`,`VerifyServerCertificate`
and so on. You only need to modify connect part to setup the secure socket before connect.

Comment: NB 'Using Winsock' is not the same thing as 'without using third party libraries such as OpenSSL or WolfSSL'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winsock itself does not offer SSL/TLS, but you can accomplish this security by using SSPI on top of Winsock via the SChannel provider, which does offer SSL/TLS. Look up [`AcquireCredentialsHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acquirecredentialshandle--schannel) and [`InitializeSecurityContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializesecuritycontext--schannel).

If you are planning on porting this to other platforms, I would seriously suggest use of OpenSSL instead, simply so that you don't have to implement your glue logic more than once.